# Trying to copy image one folder to another folder using contentResolver in android 11 but it create blank image

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, content-values

i m working on an application where i have list of images inside recyclerview and from recyclerview i have to copy my images from one folder to another folder my code is working fine in many android 11 and 12 device but in few device it creates blank images the size of blank image is in byte i don't understand what is wrong with my code

here is the code i used for copy image

```
  public static String copyFile(@NonNull final String filePath, String newName, File targetFolder, Context context) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        String folderName = targetFolder.getName();
        String relativePath;

        String fileName = new File(filePath).getName();
        String mimeType = getFileType(fileName);
        ArraySet<Uri> uries = new ArraySet<>();
        if (isImage(mimeType)) {
            uries.add(getImageUriFromFile(filePath, context));
        } else {
            uries.add(getVideoUriFromFile(filePath, context));
        }
        if (targetFolder.getPath().contains(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)) {
            relativePath = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + folderName;

        } else if (targetFolder.getPath().contains(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)) {
            relativePath = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + folderName;
        } else {
            relativePath = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + folderName;
        }

        try {
            if (isImage(new File(filePath).getName().split("\\.")[1])) {


                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(filePath);
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, newName);
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativePath);

                Uri imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

                fos = (FileOutputStream) contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
                if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)) {
                    fos.flush();
                }
                return getPath(imageUri, context);

            } else {


                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, newName);
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/" + mimeType);
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativePath);

                Uri imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);


                fos = (FileOutputStream) contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
                FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
                FileChannel outChannel = fos.getChannel();
                inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
                inStream.close();
                fos.close();
                return getPath(imageUri, context);

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and i called this method inside thread  like below.
i called this method from thread because i m doing another operation on copied file

```
 new Thread(() -> StorageUtils.copyFileOnAboveQ(
                              file1.getPath(),
                              file2.getName().split("\\.")[0],
                              file2.getParentFile(), context)).start();
```

code is working fine in many devices but in some device it create blank image

Comment: `the size of blank image is in byte` ? How many bytes?

Comment: You have to use column .IS_PENDING too. And even twice.

Comment: Your IsImage and using an intermediate bitmap is not needed. A file is a file and you can thread all files the same.

Comment: i added contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, true); and now its working perfectly. Thank you

Comment: You should use IS_PENDING twice! Also when done with update() and false.

Comment: like `contentResolver.update(imageUri,contentValues,null);
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, false);` this ?

Comment: Yes. Check the return value. It should be one row.

Comment: ok now its working properly thank u so much